# Disable and grey out a check box of treenode

Tags: c#, checkbox, treeview, treenode

I need to create a treeview that some nodes in the tree will have checkbox and other nodes will have a disable checkbox - that looks gray as disable.
once the user check the disable check box the check box image will be changed to a different image (-checked but still grey).
this treeview will have also icon , besides the check box.
(I'm using the winform treeview control)

thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't think users can check disabled check boxes... do you mean unchecked check boxes?

Comment: the check box is not really disable - just looks as disable.

Comment: that's my problem - i need to know how to change the check box image that it will be grey

Comment: You will need to use the DrawNode event to draw your own node.  MouseDown to do hit testing.  Fairly painful but not undo-able, the MSDN Library has decent example code.

Comment: Do you know a win API that can do it? -just to change the Check box image?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the ShowCheckBox property of the node to False, and the ImageUrl to a picture of a disabled checkbox. It sounds like you might be using the ImageUrl for something else, though, so you might need to create your icons for these nodes so that they show your icon and also a disabled checkbox.