# How do I disable (grey out) the checkboxes in Tri-State Tree View in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview

I am using the Tri-State Tree View which inherits from TreeView.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202435/Tri-State-Tree-View

It is clear for me how I can grey out the text:
[TreeView with multi-color TreeNode text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709814/treeview-with-multi-color-treenode-text)

Using the described event handler, I can easily change the text color of specific items in the ri-State Tree View. However, how can I change the color of **specific checkboxes** in the Tri-State Tree View so it looks like they are greyed out/disabled ?

Please note that I am using the treeview from code project, not the general TreeVieuw:
[Disable and grey out a check box of treenode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431681/disable-and-grey-out-a-check-box-of-treenode)

Comment: can you not get at the Selected Node and Set the particular Checkbox(es) that way..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there is no easy/quick way because the `TreeNode` does not have an `Enabled` property. You will have to add this functionnality yourself. I took a look at the `TriStateTreeView` code and I can make some remarks to help you.

The drawing part will be easy, you will find in the constructor :

```
case 0: CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(chkGraphics, new Point(0, 1), CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
break;
case 1: CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(chkGraphics, new Point(0, 1), CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal);
break;
case 2: CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(chkGraphics, new Point(0, 1), CheckBoxState.MixedNormal);
break;
```

this part fills the `StateImageList` that will store the bitmaps for every possible state. You will need to add three other pictures which already exist in `System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles` : `CheckBoxState.UncheckedDisabled`, `CheckBoxState.CheckedDisabled`, and `CheckBoxState.MixedDisabled`.

Then when you want to affect for instance the `CheckedDisabled` appearence to the node, you will need to change the `StateImageIndex` of the `TreeNode` property, like this `myNode.StateImageIndex = (int)CheckedState.CheckedDisabled;`

The more complex part will be the implementation of the logic. The `TriStateTreeView` only overrides five events from the `Windows.Forms.TreeView` , you will need to change them to handle your new functionnality. You will probably have to add something like this in the top :
`if(e.Node.StateImageIndex == (int)CheckedState.CheckedDisabled || ... ) return;` but it may not be that simple in every case so make sure you check every method.